# How to export data to Google spreadsheet

Tags: codeigniter, google-docs, google-sheets-api

Using CodeIgniter 1.7.2, is there any library to import data to a Google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about the Google spreadsheet API, but I'm assuming it can accept a CSV file, so that is where I would start.

CodeIgniter offers a way to create a CSV file from your database [check out the user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html/)

```
$this->dbutil->csv_from_result($db_result);
```

I would generate a CSV then via the Google API send it up to the server and that should work.  Again, I don't know anything about the spreadsheet API, so I could be way off base, but since no one else has responded I figured I'd help out as best I can.

Answer (score 0):

This is potentially a good article on the subject, [Saving Form Data to Google Spreadsheets Using PHP and the Google Docs API](http://www.farinspace.com/saving-form-data-to-google-spreadsheets/), it includes a Helper class and step by step instructions.